# Why does the thread end without waiting for input?

Tags: python, multithreading, input

"What's your name?" is printed five times, but I can not get input() to work. Why does the program end without requiring five user inputs? When using threads - what could be done to get the 5 inputs?

```
import threading

def user_input():
    print("Inside user_input")
    ui = input("What's your name? ")
    return ui

threads = []
for i in range(5):
    t = threading.Thread(target=user_input)
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()
```

Comment: Because the main thread has exited causing program termination.

Comment: You have to `join()` your threads.

Comment: @selbie and @KlausD,  If the threads are not daemon threads, which they are not, they should continue to run even *after* the main thread terminates. When I run this, I have no problem entering all 5 inputs. When I change the `return ui` statement to a `print(ui)` statement, I see what was input.

Comment: See it working [here](http://ideone.com/AamwN2) (although admittedly the timing is different).

Comment: Or [here](http://ideone.com/HLk8T2) with a call to `sleep` to ensure the main thread has terminated.

Answer (score 0):

Try less code, as follows. This works on linux.  The posted code does not work on windows, but does on linux.

INPUT CODE:

```
import threading

def user_input():
    input("What's your name? ")

threads = []
for i in range(5):
    t = threading.Thread(target=user_input)
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()
```

OUTPUT:

```
Python 3.7.4 (default, Jul  9 2019, 00:06:43)
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux
What's your name? test
What's your name? test
What's your name? test
What's your name? test
```

Comment: which part of the answer has wrong indentation? begining, code or output?

Comment: `input("What's your name? ")` needs to be indented and the three lines under `for i in range(5):` need to be indented. Why don't you try copying and pasting what you posted and try running it before you get downvoted.

Comment: Also, as far as I can tell, the only difference between your code and the OP's is the removal of `print("Inside user_input")` and an innocuous `return` statement. As I commented, I actually found the OP's code to work on my Windows platform.

Comment: OP's code hangs on my Windows 10. Python exe dir, python script dir, path and pathext have python adds, python._pth has all dir. I got it to work on linux though with said removal of star 'n'. Also, running through script editor that works with other scripts in python script directory.

Comment: I am still on Windows 7.